# How do you round a number to two decimal places in C#?

Tags: c#, decimal, rounding, bankers-rounding

I want to do this using the `Math.Round` function

Answer (score 816):

Here's some examples:

```
decimal a = 1.994444M;

Math.Round(a, 2); //returns 1.99

decimal b = 1.995555M;

Math.Round(b, 2); //returns 2.00
```

You might also want to look at bankers rounding / round-to-even with the following overload:

```
Math.Round(a, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
```

There's more information on it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round-to-even_method).

Comment: You should clarify that MidPointRounding.ToEven IS the default.  If you wanted AwayFromZero you would have to use the overload

Comment: If you wanted to **round up** to 2 decimal places, add `0.005` to the number before rounding. Likewise to **round down**, subtract `0.005` before passing to `Math.Round` function.

Comment: The reason that .NET defaults to `MidPointRounding.ToEven` (aka "Bankers Rounding") is because the we all learned to round in school where .5 rounds up causes too much rounding up. This is a problem when dealing with money, tax calculations, etc.

Answer (score 126):

Try this:

```
twoDec = Math.Round(val, 2)
```

Answer (score 48):

If you'd like a string

```
> (1.7289).ToString("#.##")
"1.73"
```

Or a decimal

```
> Math.Round((Decimal)x, 2)
1.73m
```

---

But remember! Rounding is not distributive, ie. `round(x*y) != round(x) * round(y)`. So don't do any rounding until the very end of a calculation, else you'll lose accuracy.

Answer (score 36):

Personally I never round anything. Keep it as resolute as possible, since rounding is a bit of a red herring in CS anyway. But you do want to format data for your users, and to that end, I find that `string.Format("{0:0.00}", number)` is a good approach.

Comment: This works better for display purposes, especially for money, as £5.4 (with Math.round) doesn't look as well as £5.40 (this way).

Comment: I've tried before string.Format("0:0.00", number), but it didn't work. Those square brackets are very important, so: string.Format("{0:0.00}", number) works.

Comment: @FrenkyB When you say 'square brackets', I hope you mean braces.

Comment: This rounds also. 1.009 => 1.01

Answer (score 16):

[Wikipedia has a nice page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) on rounding in general.

All .NET (managed) languages can use any of the common language run time's (the CLR) rounding mechanisms.  For example, the [Math.Round()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k(VS.95).aspx) (as mentioned above) method allows the developer to specify the type of rounding (Round-to-even or Away-from-zero). The Convert.ToInt32() method and its variations use [round-to-even](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx).  The [Ceiling()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48(VS.95).aspx) and [Floor()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb(VS.95).aspx) methods are related.

You can round with [custom numeric formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(VS.95).aspx) as well.

Note that [Decimal.Round()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.round(VS.71).aspx) uses a different method than Math.Round();

Here is a [useful pos](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/26/bankers-rounding.aspx)t on the banker's rounding algorithm.
See one of Raymond's humorous [posts here](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/26/360797.aspx) about rounding...

Comment: Can you expand on "Decimal.Round()" uses a different method than Math.Round()"? As of 14 years (!) after you posted this, it doesn't look like there's any difference.

Answer (score 16):

// convert upto two decimal places

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 140.6767554);        // "140.67"
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 140.1);             // "140.10"
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 140);              // "140.00"

Double d = 140.6767554;
Double dc = Math.Round((Double)d, 2);       //  140.67

decimal d = 140.6767554M;
decimal dc = Math.Round(d, 2);             //  140.67
```

=========

```
// just two decimal places
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.4);         // "123.4"
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.0);         // "123"
```

can also combine "0" with "#".

```
String.Format("{0:0.0#}", 123.4567)       // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.0#}", 123.4)          // "123.4"
String.Format("{0:0.0#}", 123.0)          // "123.0"
```

Comment: String.Format("{0:0.00}", 140.6767554);    !=  "140.67"

It actually renders as "140.68" - rounding up

Answer (score 10):

If you want to round a number, you can obtain different results depending on: how you use the Math.Round() function (if for a round-up or round-down), you're working with doubles and/or floats numbers, and you apply the midpoint rounding. Especially, when using with operations inside of it or the variable to round comes from an operation. Let's say, you want to multiply these two numbers: **0.75 * 0.95 = 0.7125**. Right? Not in C#

Let's see what happens if you want to round to the 3rd decimal:

```
double result = 0.75d * 0.95d; // result = 0.71249999999999991
double result = 0.75f * 0.95f; // result = 0.71249997615814209

result = Math.Round(result, 3, MidpointRounding.ToEven); // result = 0.712. Ok
result = Math.Round(result, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // result = 0.712. Should be 0.713
```

As you see, the first Round() is correct if you want to round down the midpoint. But the second Round() it's wrong if you want to round up.

This applies to negative numbers:

```
double result = -0.75 * 0.95;  //result = -0.71249999999999991
result = Math.Round(result, 3, MidpointRounding.ToEven); // result = -0.712. Ok
result = Math.Round(result, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // result = -0.712. Should be -0.713
```

So, IMHO, you should create your own wrap function for Math.Round() that fit your requirements. I created a function in which, the parameter 'roundUp=true' means to round to next greater number. That is: 0.7125 rounds to 0.713 and -0.7125 rounds to -0.712 (because -0.712 > -0.713). This is the function I created and works for any number of decimals:

```
double Redondea(double value, int precision, bool roundUp = true)
{
    if ((decimal)value == 0.0m)
        return 0.0;

    double corrector = 1 / Math.Pow(10, precision + 2);

    if ((decimal)value < 0.0m)
    {
        if (roundUp)
            return Math.Round(value, precision, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
        else
            return Math.Round(value - corrector, precision, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    }
    else
    {
        if (roundUp)
            return Math.Round(value + corrector, precision, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        else
            return Math.Round(value, precision, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
    }
}
```

The variable  'corrector' is for fixing the inaccuracy of operating with floating or double numbers.

Answer (score 9):

This is for rounding to 2 decimal places in C#:

```
label8.Text = valor_cuota .ToString("N2") ;
```

In VB.NET:

```
 Imports System.Math
 round(label8.text,2)
```

Answer (score 7):

I know its an old question but please note for the following differences between **Math round** and **String format round**:

```
decimal d1 = (decimal)1.125;
Math.Round(d1, 2).Dump();   // returns 1.12
d1.ToString("#.##").Dump(); // returns "1.13"

decimal d2 = (decimal)1.1251;
Math.Round(d2, 2).Dump();   // returns 1.13
d2.ToString("#.##").Dump(); // returns "1.13"
```

Answer (score 7):

Had a weird situation where I had a decimal variable, when serializing 55.50 it always sets default value mathematically as 55.5. But whereas, our client system is seriously expecting 55.50 for some reason and they definitely expected decimal. Thats when I had write the below helper, which always converts any decimal value padded to 2 digits with zeros instead of sending a string.

```
public static class DecimalExtensions
{
    public static decimal WithTwoDecimalPoints(this decimal val)
    {
        return decimal.Parse(val.ToString("0.00"));
    }
}
```

Usage should be

```
var sampleDecimalValueV1 = 2.5m;
Console.WriteLine(sampleDecimalValueV1.WithTwoDecimalPoints());

decimal sampleDecimalValueV1 = 2;
Console.WriteLine(sampleDecimalValueV1.WithTwoDecimalPoints());
```

Output:

```
2.50
2.00
```

Answer (score 4):

One thing you may want to check is the Rounding Mechanism of Math.Round:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx

Other than that, I recommend the Math.Round(inputNumer, numberOfPlaces) approach over the *100/100 one because it's cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

Simply `Math.Round()` solves this problem and fits the situation by passing a `precision` parameter and `MidpointRounding` parameter to the method.

By default `Math.Round` uses `MidpointRounding.ToEven` which is actually `bankers rounding` meaning that the halfway numbers round to the nearest even number:

```
1.5 => 2
2.5 => 2
3.5 => 4
4.5 => 4
```

Let me make it clear. Actually, there are 5 strategies of `MidpointRounding` you could take to get what you expect from `Math.Round()`:

1. **ToEven (default)** When a number is halfway between two others, it is rounded toward the nearest even number.
2. **AwayFromZero (mathematical rounding)** When a number is halfway between two others, it is rounded toward the nearest number away from zero. (Aka, round up)
3. **ToZero** rounds down the number based on specified precision
4. **ToNegativeInfinity (floor)** rounds down the number based on specified precision
5. **ToPositiveInfinity (ceiling)** rounds up the number based on specified precision.

Here is the code to see exactly how they work:

```
var num1 = 1.5;
var num2 = 2.5;
var num3 = 3.5;
var num4 = 2.51;
var num5 = 2.48;

Console.WriteLine("----------------Round with MidpointRounding.ToEven (default) ---------------------");
Console.WriteLine($"{num1} => {Math.Round(num1, MidpointRounding.ToEven)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num2} => {Math.Round(num2, MidpointRounding.ToEven)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num3} => {Math.Round(num3, MidpointRounding.ToEven)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num4} => {Math.Round(num4, MidpointRounding.ToEven)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num5} => {Math.Round(num5, MidpointRounding.ToEven)}");

Console.WriteLine("----------------Round with MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero (mathematical rounding) ---------------------");
Console.WriteLine($"{num1} => {Math.Round(num1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num2} => {Math.Round(num2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num3} => {Math.Round(num3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num4} => {Math.Round(num4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num5} => {Math.Round(num5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)}");

Console.WriteLine("----------------Round with MidpointRounding.ToZero ---------------------");
Console.WriteLine($"{num1} => {Math.Round(num1, MidpointRounding.ToZero)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num2} => {Math.Round(num2, MidpointRounding.ToZero)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num3} => {Math.Round(num3, MidpointRounding.ToZero)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num4} => {Math.Round(num4, MidpointRounding.ToZero)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num5} => {Math.Round(num5, MidpointRounding.ToZero)}");

Console.WriteLine("----------------Round with MidpointRounding.ToNegativeInfinity (floor) ---------------------");
Console.WriteLine($"{num1} => {Math.Round(num1, MidpointRounding.ToNegativeInfinity)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num2} => {Math.Round(num2, MidpointRounding.ToNegativeInfinity)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num3} => {Math.Round(num3, MidpointRounding.ToNegativeInfinity)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num4} => {Math.Round(num4, MidpointRounding.ToNegativeInfinity)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num5} => {Math.Round(num5, MidpointRounding.ToNegativeInfinity)}");

Console.WriteLine("----------------Round with MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity (ceiling) ---------------------");
Console.WriteLine($"{num1} => {Math.Round(num1, MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num2} => {Math.Round(num2, MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num3} => {Math.Round(num3, MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num4} => {Math.Round(num4, MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num5} => {Math.Round(num5, MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity)}");
```

the result:

```
----------------Round with MidpointRounding.ToEven (default) ---------------------
1.5 => 2
2.5 => 2
3.5 => 4
2.51 => 3
2.48 => 2
----------------Round with MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero (mathematical rounding) ---------------------
1.5 => 2
2.5 => 3
3.5 => 4
2.51 => 3
2.48 => 2
----------------Round with MidpointRounding.ToZero ---------------------
1.5 => 1
2.5 => 2
3.5 => 3
2.51 => 2
2.48 => 2
----------------Round with MidpointRounding.ToNegativeInfinity ---------------------
1.5 => 1
2.5 => 2
3.5 => 3
2.51 => 2
2.48 => 2
----------------Round with MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity ---------------------
1.5 => 2
2.5 => 3
3.5 => 4
2.51 => 3
2.48 => 3
```

Comment: don't copy and paste answers. customize the answer to the question. you have a bunch of useless noise here

Comment: when someone gets here from a Google search there should be a complete explanation of how things work exactly, to fully understand the usage, and I clearly explained for everyone who reaches this page to get the answer to their problem

Comment: take the [tour]. one of the whole points of this platform is to avoid noise.

Comment: So how could others find the whole explanation of a topic or a problem?

Comment: find a question that actually asks this info and then write this as an answer there.

Comment: I deleted my other answer to that similar question, and put the link to this answer there! thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to specify the number of digits you want to round to using Math.Round(YourNumber, 2)

You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

**Math.Floor(123456.646 * 100) / 100**
Would return 123456.64

Answer (score 1):

string a = "10.65678";

decimal d = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(a.ToString()),2)

Answer (score 0):

```
  public double RoundDown(double number, int decimalPlaces)
        {
            return Math.Floor(number * Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces)) / Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces);
        }
```