# sql round function

Tags: sql

i need to round one decimal value to deicmal places which is passes as parameter.
By doing :
select round(n,@a) from tbl_Test

where n is of type decimal 18,4 
and @a=2
i got result but two zeros is added at the end.
I want to get result without that zeros..but return value should be of ype decimal..not string.

Is it possible anything like : cast(round(n,@a) as decimal(18,@a))?

Comment: Why are you trying to do display formatting in the database? It shouldn't matter how many additional zeros are returned. Let the consuming application or report format the values so they look right.

Comment: Did you get the answer you were looking for?  If so, could you please accept it?  If not, could you clarify what you are still looking for?  Usually, the more information you provide, the more likely it is someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only 2 decimals, you'll need to change the scale in the definition to 2.  So, exactly as you supposed:

> cast(round(n,@a) as decimal(18,@a))

MS SQL Server does not support the use of parameters in data type definitions.  Now, "client" code does.  So, an approach like this might work for you, ( either written in a db sproc with t-sql or in business layer with c# or whatever ).

```
use tempdb;
go
create 
--drop 
table tbl_test 
( n  decimal ( 18, 4 ) );
declare @n as decimal ( 18, 4 );
SET @n = 12.0006;
insert into tbl_test ( n ) values ( @n );
SET @n = 12.0060;
insert into tbl_test ( n ) values ( @n );
SET @n = 12.0600;
insert into tbl_test ( n ) values ( @n );
SET @n = 12.6000;
insert into tbl_test ( n ) values ( @n );

select 
    cast ( round ( n, 2 ) as decimal ( 18, 2 ) )
    , n
from tbl_test
order by n ASC

declare @var_scale integer;
set @var_scale = 2;
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
select 
    cast ( round ( n, @a ) as decimal ( 18, @a ) )
    , n
from tbl_test
order by n ASC
'
set @sql = REPLACE ( @sql, '@a', @var_scale );
execute ( @sql );
```

---

But, much like Thomas said in the first comment to your question, without a pretty good explanation as to why, this would seem like pure folly.  For instance, in C#, one would, as one consumed values in field n, simply round to 2 places.  See [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257005/how-do-you-round-a-number-to-two-decimal-places-in-c) article.  If the client is a Crystal Reports or Sql Server Reporting Services, you have the same sort of options-both have built in functions which perform the rounding for you.  It may take some doing, but you can probably pass user defined scale values to them as well.