# How to include decimal point to string in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, decimal, decimal-point

How to add decimal point (with two decimal places) to string, without converting string to decimal?

For example (Dim str1 as String), regardless str1 has value: 100 , 100.0 , 100.00, or 100.5 , 100.50...
I'd like to get the output: 100.00 or 100.50, with two decimal places.

Comment: `CDec(myString).ToString("D2")` isn't so prohibitive that you should balk at it. Just cast and call `ToString`.

Comment: don't know vb but in c# convert it to decimal, round it up and then convert back to string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257005/how-do-you-round-a-number-to-two-decimal-places-in-c

Comment: I have tried with `CDec(myString).ToString("D2")`, but I got Exception error: ex.Message = "Format specifier was invalid."
This is my code: 
`Dim str1 As String = "100.0"` `Dim str2 As String` `str2 = CDec(str1).ToString("D2")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Function FormatNumber(ByVal s As String) As String
    Dim pos As Integer = s.IndexOf("."c)
    If pos = -1 Then ' No decimal point
        Return s & ".00"
    Else
        Return (s & "00").Substring(0, pos + 3)
    End If
End Function
```

---

And since you inserted a C# tag:

```cs
public string FormatNumber(string s)
{
    int pos = s.IndexOf('.');
    if (pos == -1) { // No decimal point 
        return s + ".00";
    } else {
        return (s + "00").Substring(0, pos + 3);
    }
}
```

---

However, note that superfluous decimals will be truncated - no rounding occurs!

Answer (score 0):

Can't add comment yet, so excuse the additional post...

lthibodeaux and dierre are correct.  Converting to decimal and back is much better.  Otherwise you could create a function that looks for a decimal point in the string and then appends zeroes to it based on where it finds it.  The problem is if you get a str like "13.876".  You would have to figure out how to do rounding on the string.

Go the easy route.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Shared Function TwoDecimalString(input As String) As String
    Dim output As String
    Dim splittedInput As String() = input.Split("."C)
    If splittedInput.Length = 1 Then
        output = input & ".00"
    Else
        output = splittedInput(0) & "." & splittedInput(1).PadRight(2, "0"C)
    End If
    Return output
End Function
```