# Rounding a variable to two decimal places C#

Tags: c#, variables, decimal, rounding

I am interested in how to round variables to two decimal places. In the example below, the bonus is usually a number with four decimal places. Is there any way to ensure the pay variable is always rounded to two decimal places?

```
  pay = 200 + bonus;
  Console.WriteLine(pay);
```

Comment: Google search? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257005/how-do-you-round-a-number-to-two-decimal-places-in-c

Comment: Homework tag is obsolete

Comment: wow HomeWork tag?? just saw it now, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated?cb=1

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Use [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx) and specify the number of decimal places.

```
Math.Round(pay,2);
```

[Math.Round Method (Double, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx)

> Rounds a **double-precision floating-point** value to a specified number
>   of fractional digits.

Or [Math.Round Method (Decimal, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k.aspx)

> Rounds a decimal value to a specified number of fractional digits.

Comment: And make sure you're using a `float`, `double` or `decimal` type, otherwise this won't ever work.

Comment: I am using a double, but it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: call it like `pay = Math.Round(pay, 2);`

Comment: Important: this will round 0.005 to 0.00! See why that is in Jon's answer below, which should be the top answer.

Answer (score 37):

You should use a form of [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as4h66hd.aspx).  Be aware that `Math.Round` defaults to banker's rounding (rounding to the nearest even number) unless you specify a [`MidpointRounding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx) value.  If you don't want to use banker's rounding, you should use [`Math.Round(decimal d, int decimals, MidpointRounding mode)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131274.aspx), like so:

```
Math.Round(pay, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // .005 rounds up to 0.01
Math.Round(pay, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);       // .005 rounds to nearest even (0.00) 
Math.Round(pay, 2);    // Defaults to MidpointRounding.ToEven
```

([Why does .NET use banker's rounding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311696/why-does-net-use-bankers-rounding-as-default))

Answer (score 6):

```
decimal pay  = 1.994444M;

Math.Round(pay , 2);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can round the result and use `string.Format` to set the precision like this:

```
decimal pay = 200.5555m;
pay = Math.Round(pay + bonus, 2);
string payAsString = string.Format("{0:0.00}", pay);
```

Comment: I doubt you can use `pay` in two different senses in the first line! When you already use `Math.Round`, maybe it's not nexessary to use string formatting as well? If you don't want to round the actual number struct, but only want to shorten the string produced, string formatting is a nice thing. In that case, also consider `"F"` or `"F2"` (and `"N"`, `"N2"`) formatting strings, i.e. for example `string.Format("{0:N}", pay)` or equivalently `pay.ToString("N")`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You're absolutely right about the first line! Amended. Interesting, I'd never used `{0:N}` before, creature of habit I suppose ;o)

Comment: To explain further, `"F"` rounds to a number of decimals specified by the `NumberFormat` of the current culture of the current thread. This would often be two decimals. `"F2"` always rounds to two decimals. `"N"` and `"N2"` are similar but they also insert group separators according to the culture. For example `(11223344.5566m).ToString("N")` might produce the formatted number `"11,223,344.56"` in some culture. See [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Use System.Math.Round to rounds a decimal value to a specified number of fractional digits.

```
var pay = 200 + bonus;
pay = System.Math.Round(pay, 2);
Console.WriteLine(pay);
```

MSDN References:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you provide a number, typically a double is used. Math.Round can take 1-3 arguments, the first argument is the variable you wish to round, the second is the number of decimal places and the third is the type of rounding.

```
double pay = 200 + bonus;
double pay = Math.Round(pay);
// Rounds to nearest even number, rounding 0.5 will round "down" to zero because zero is even
double pay = Math.Round(pay, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
// Rounds up to nearest number
double pay = Math.Round(pay, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention on fact that `Round` **rounds**.

So (I don't know if it matters in your industry or not), but:

```
float a = 12.345f;
Math.Round(a,2);

//result:12,35, and NOT 12.34 !
```

To make it more precise for *your case* we can do something like this:

```
int aInt = (int)(a*100);
float aFloat= aInt /100.0f;
//result:12,34
```

Comment: Math.Round is not accepting a float number as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine(decimal.Round(pay,2));
```