# C# Rounding 1.998 to 1.9

Tags: c#, rounding

I have read many examples of rounding numbers but nothing that solves my problem...

I may be missing something obvious but I tried:

```
string.Format("{0:0.0}", 1.998) = "2.0"
(1.998).ToString("0.0") = "2.0"
(1.998).ToString("0.#") = "2"
Math.Round(1.998, 1) = 2
```

I need: **1.9**

Note: value 1.998 could be 1.998xxx

Seemed pretty simple but can't get this result...

Comment: Why should 1.998 be rounded to 1.9? Do you want to round down to one decimal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding down to 2 decimal places in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13522095/rounding-down-to-2-decimal-places-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I know the duplicate is not perfect, but you should be able to transform the solution from 2 to 1 decimal places ;)

Comment: What result do you expect for -1.998 as the input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to truncate from what I understand. Try this:

```
(Math.Truncate(1.998m * 10))/10
```

*Forcing `decimal` instead of `double` prevents problems with floating point calculations. Also, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14/difference-between-math-floor-and-math-truncate/580252#580252) which explains rounding differences between `Truncate`, `Round`, `Floor` and `Ceiling` to find out which one suits your needs best.*

Comment: Thanks ! This seems to give me the result I need.

But I raises another question, using doubles for my variables, I get this strange result:
`code`0.6 + 0.3 = 0.89999999999999991`code`

Comment: About this strange result: 0.6 + 0.3 = 0.89999999999999991

Forcing to decimal like you sugested in your answer, did the trick ! Thanks twice !