# Round Down Value Using VB.net

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone give me some help on how to round half down in Visual Basic? I need **1.235** to be converted to **1.23 and NOT 1.24.**

Comment: Read the documentation for the `Math.Round` or `Decimal.Round` method, depending on which one you're using. All the information you need is there. ALWAYS read the relevant documentation before posting a question.

Comment: using math.round value 1.235  Is Converted  to 1.24 & by using Decimal.Round value 1.235  Is Converted  to 1

Comment: @Max Yes, you can't use `Math.Round()` for this purpose if you're using .NET Framework or .NET Core <3.0 (at least not directly). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13522109/8967612) for more information. It's for C# but the logic is the same. You'll need to either use `Math.Floor()` with multiplication and division as demonstrated in the duplicate linked above, or you could write your own custom method that uses `Math.Round()` as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13575296/8967612).

Comment: On the other hand, if you're using .NET Core 3+ or .NET 5+, you can simply do `Math.Round(1.235, 2, MidpointRounding.ToZero)` or `.Round(1.235, 2, MidpointRounding.ToNegativeInfinity)` (depending on how you want to handle negative values).

Answer (score 1):

What is in the comments,

```
    Const numD As Integer = 100 'for 3 digits 1000, etc.
    Dim d As Double = 1.235#
    Dim d1 As Double
    d1 = Math.Round(d, 2)
    Stop
    d1 = Math.Round(d, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
    Stop
    d1 = Math.Round(d, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven)
    Stop
    d1 = Math.Sign(d) * Math.Floor(Math.Abs(d) * numD) / numD 'winner winner
    Stop
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim value As double = 1.235
value = Math.Floor(value * 100) / 100
```

Comment: FWIW - this won't work for negative numbers.