# c# -Which Math function i need to use to convert 1.7272 to 1.73

Tags: c#, .net

I have tried many Math function in the c# to convert 1.7272 to 1.73 but did not got any function working to achieve my goal.
I wants a simple conversion which is 1.7272 to 1.73

Please suggest me which Math function can do work for me?

Thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa340225%28v=vs.71%29.aspx o.O - hint hint: Math.Round( number, 2 ); // 2 decimals after

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257005/how-do-you-round-a-number-to-two-decimal-places-in-c

Comment: Here's a custom converter: `if (value == 1.7272) { return 1.73; }` ?

Comment: @GrantThomas you gotta be kidding

Comment: this question is too common. `:D` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257005/how-do-you-round-a-number-to-two-decimal-places-in-c

Comment: @fvu Kinda. If the question was worded that this would need to work for _any other value_, then perhaps I would have refrained. As it stands, the OP _always_ has a value of 1.7272 and _always_ wants it to turn into 1.73. I don't believe this to be true, mind you. But, generalise and use a literal example.

Comment: @GrantThomas: It certainly matches the spec, and would pass the unit test!

Comment: @GrantThomas I am sorry I miscredited ;-); I spent to much time with those nasty salesman people specifying stuff (like "its always x" ) and then complain if its outside the spec and misbehaving. You are right, always stick to the spec and fix unit-tests to run through :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use Math.Round:

```
Math.Round(1.7272, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like a string

```
> (1.7272).ToString("#.##")
"1.73"
```

Or a decimal

```
> Math.Round(((Decimal)1.7272), 2)
1.73m
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.Round(1.7272,2)` is what you you are looking for...

Answer (score 0):

The .Round function will help you

```
System.Math.Round(1.7272, 2) returns 1.73
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double d = Math.Round(1.7272, 2);
```