# Round to 1 decimal place in C#

Tags: c#, rounding

I would like to round my answer 1 decimal place. for example: 6.7, 7.3, etc.
But when I use Math.round, the answer always come up with no decimal places. For example: 6, 7

Here is the code that I used:

```
int [] nbOfNumber = new int[ratingListBox.Items.Count];
int sumInt = 0;
double averagesDoubles;

for (int g = 0; g < nbOfNumber.Length; g++)
{
    nbOfNumber[g] = int.Parse(ratingListBox.Items[g].Text);
}

for (int h = 0; h < nbOfNumber.Length; h++)
{
    sumInt += nbOfNumber[h];
}

averagesDoubles = (sumInt / ratingListBox.Items.Count);
averagesDoubles = Math.Round(averagesDoubles, 2);
averageRatingTextBox.Text = averagesDoubles.ToString();
```

Comment: Your variables are not defined

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257005/how-do-you-round-a-number-to-two-decimal-places-in-c

Comment: i did the same but the answer is still appears to have no decimal places ?...

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You're dividing by an `int`, it wil give an `int` as result. *(which makes 13 / 7 = 1)*

Try casting it to a floating point first:

```
averagesDoubles = (sumInt / (double)ratingListBox.Items.Count);
```

The `averagesDoubles = Math.Round(averagesDoubles, 2);` is reponsible for rounding the double value. It will round, `5.976` to `5.98`, but this doesn't affect the presentation of the value.

The `ToString()` is responsible for the presentation of decimals.

Try :

```
averagesDoubles.ToString("0.0");
```

Comment: I wanted to display to one decimal place and .ToString("0.0") worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

Do verify that `averagesDoubles`  is either double or decimal as per the definition of [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx) and combine these two lines :

```
averagesDoubles = (sumInt / ratingListBox.Items.Count);
averagesDoubles = Math.Round(averagesDoubles, 2);
```

TO :

```
averagesDoubles = Math.Round((sumInt / ratingListBox.Items.Count),2);
```

2 in the above case represents the number of decimals you want to round upto. Check the link above for more reference.

Answer (score 1):

int division will always ignore  fraction

```
 (sumInt / ratingListBox.Items.Count);
```

here sumint is int and ratingListBox.Items.Count is also int , so divison never results in fraction

to get the value in fraction , you need to  datatype like float and type cast the sumInt  and count to float and double and then use divison

Answer (score -2):

var val= Math.Ceiling(100.10m);
result 101