# Convert a value to only show 1 decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting a value that looks like 17.55453304545 (just as an example), from a database. But I want it to show with one decimal, so that it looks like: 17.6, before it is shown to the aspx page. I don't have access to change the value in tha database tabel, so I must do it in the C# code instead.
I have tried:

```
double result = (Convert.ToDouble(this.GetFieldValue("value"));
```

But the value does not change. Come to think of it, then I think that it is because I use double? The value is probably a double at first.

Comment: How do you show the value? You have to apply formatter there (something like `double.ToString("R1"`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use [string formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to display it, rather than displaying the raw value.  For example,

```
String.Format("{0:0.0}", myDoubleValue)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
double result = Math.Round(this.GetFieldValue("value"), 1);
```

You can change 1 to any other number of decimal places. refer to this post for more info [How do you round a number to two decimal places in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257005/how-do-you-round-a-number-to-two-decimal-places-in-c)

Comment: I guess it would rather be:


Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(this.GetFieldValue("value")), 1);
And thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to show it use:

```
var value = (17.55453304545).ToString("#.#");
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
var formatted = result.ToString("f1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
double roundUp = Math.Round(Value, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```