# how to round value to only 3 decimal points?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, types

i am working on a inventory software and was calculating the discount by percentage and amount as well.

- means when i enter % amount it automatically convert to price#
- and when i enter price it automatically converts to the % #

the code i am using to convert price in % is this is:

```
if(txtDiscount.Text == "" || txtGrandTotal.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter amount in Grand Total",Application.ProductName,MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
              //  double percent;
                double grandTotal;
                double per;
                double txDiscount;

                //percent = Convert.ToInt32(txtPercant.Text);
                grandTotal = Convert.ToInt32(txtGrandTotal.Text);
                txDiscount = Convert.ToInt32(txtDiscount.Text);


                per = txDiscount / grandTotal * 100;

                //per = percent / 100 * grandTotal;

                if (per % 3 != 0)
                    per = (per - per % 3) + 3;


                txtPercant.Text = Convert.ToString(per);

                    ................
                    ................
                    ................
                    ................
                    ................
```

now let's suppose if i am entering the amount is "25", then the percentage it count is "2.77777777777778". i want to limit this to three decimals after point, like i want to to be "2.778" or whatever means i want to to show only 3 decimals after point, can any one help me out in which way i can do it ?? any suggestions would be appreciated!!

### EDIT:

Coversion from Price to % Code is:

```
  private void txtDiscount_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
            if(txtDiscount.Text == "" || txtGrandTotal.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter amount in Grand Total",Application.ProductName,MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
              //  double percent;
                double grandTotal;
                double per;
                double txDiscount;

                //percent = Convert.ToInt32(txtPercant.Text);
                grandTotal = Convert.ToInt32(txtGrandTotal.Text);
                txDiscount = Convert.ToInt32(txtDiscount.Text);


                per = txDiscount / grandTotal * 100;

                //per =  Math.Round(per, 3);
                per = Math.Truncate(per * 1000) / 1000;

                txtPercant.Text = Convert.ToString(per);








                double lblgrandTotal = 0.0;
                double Disconunt = 0.0;
                double netTotal = 0.0;

                lblgrandTotal = Convert.ToDouble(txtGrandTotal.Text);
                Disconunt = Convert.ToDouble(txtDiscount.Text);
                netTotal = grandTotal - Disconunt;

            //netTotal = Convert.ToInt32(grandTotal) - Convert.ToInt32(Discount);

            lblNetTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(netTotal);

            }
        }
```

Cobersion from % to Price Code is :

```
   private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtPercant.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter value in Percenent", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                double percent;
                double grandTotal;
                double per;

                percent = Convert.ToDouble(txtPercant.Text);
                grandTotal = Convert.ToDouble(txtGrandTotal.Text);

                per = percent / 100 * grandTotal;

                txtDiscount.Text = Convert.ToString(per);

                double lblgrandTotal = 0.0;
                double Disconunt = 0.0;
                double netTotal = 0.0;

                lblgrandTotal = Convert.ToDouble(txtGrandTotal.Text);
                Disconunt = Convert.ToDouble(txtDiscount.Text);
                netTotal = grandTotal - Disconunt;

                //netTotal = Convert.ToInt32(grandTotal) - Convert.ToInt32(Discount);

                lblNetTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(netTotal);
            }
        }
```

but the problem i am facing is i am converting % to price and Vise Versa, now in case i am adding 12 in Price it says 12.33%, and when i put 12.33% it converts back it to 11.997Price which is not the same ans it should be... it should be exactly 12 not 11.997... really confused in it..!!

### NOTE:

by price i mean that i am calculating % discount and price discount on grand total, means if i add 12% then it calculate the price discount of grand total and if i enter the price amount then it calculates the %discount of grand total

Comment: `Math.Round(2.77777777777778, 3)`

Comment: i want to convert the value in per variable not the actual value i don't know which value user is entering each time bro @L.B

Comment: @L.B Thanks Worked out for me :)

Comment: @L.B one more prob arise here, when i am entering 12 in Price it says 12.33%, and when i put 12.33% it converts back it to 11.997RS which is not the same ans it should be... :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you round a number to two decimal places in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257005/how-do-you-round-a-number-to-two-decimal-places-in-c)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Math.Round(per, 3)`

However, you've two logical errors in your approach. You are using `double` to deal with amounts of money and percentages applied to it.

`double` is appropriate for use with natural things in the real world, like the length of your nose, or the number of seconds between a celebrity being arrested and a joke about it appearing on Twitter.

Money and percentage discounts are not natural things, but artificial amounts based on particular numbering systems.

Almost all of these are decimal based, except for Mauritanian ouguiyas, Malagasy ariaries, and the Maltese scudo, and several obsolete currencies (like the old British pound, shillings and pence). Of the three used in current times, the first two are base-5 based (and so representable without error in a decimal system) and the last is pegged to the Euro, so there's no need to worry about it.

Now, when we deal with the real world we get problems because our numbering system is in a particular base, and so we get results like `0.33333333333333333333333333333`.

With money, we can only get these mistakes with division, because unless we divide, nothing will force a base-limit error upon us.

But `double` doesn't use decimal internally, it uses binary. Binary has different numbers that result in recurrent digits after the point. E.g. `0.1` and `0.01`. Most of the time the rounding errors involved will cancel out, but sometimes they won't.

Hence, when dealing with money, always use `decimal` rather than `double` unless you've a very good reason (if you can't explain why the above doesn't apply to your case, then you don't).

The second problem is that since you're doing percentages, you are doing division, and so you will still get some rounding errors.

The solution is to store one more decimal places than you need. E.g. if you want to be accurate to 3 decimal places (as you say) then store 4.

For example, if at some point we divided 12 by 7 and rounded to three points, we'd have 1.714. If we then multiplied by 7 again, we'd have 11.998. If however we'd stored the four-decimal 1.7143 and only displayed 1.714, then multiplying by 7 again would give us 12.0001 which we'd display (rounding to 3 places again) as 12.

We can't avoid rounding errors, but we can work at a higher precision until the latest moment necessary, so the rounding errors are themselves lost to rounding.

Comment: Nice story, you should write a book on this subject. :)

Comment: @Bazzz, I've only written books on religious and magical subjects to date, but do feel free to search for me on Amazon if you're interested.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution :**  if you want to get only 3 digits after decimal point you can follow below steps:

**Step 1:** multiply the double value (percentage) with `1000` to move the decimal point after 3 digits from current position.

**Step 2:** Truncate the decimal part as we dont need the digits after current decimal position using `Math.Truncate()` Method.

**Step 3:** now divide the result(truncated part) with `1000` move the decimal point before 3 digits.

Note : make sure that before converting from `DiscountPercentage` to `DiscountPrice` set `DiscountPrice` textbox value `zero` and vice versa.

Try This:

```
     per = Math.Truncate(per * 1000) / 1000;
```

**EDIT :** you have added only one way conversion:

Try This:

```
       if (txtDiscount.Text == "" || txtGrandTotal.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter amount in Grand Total", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            //  double percent;
            double grandTotal;
            double per;
            double txDiscount;

            //percent = Convert.ToInt32(txtPercant.Text);
            grandTotal = Convert.ToInt32(txtGrandTotal.Text);
            txDiscount = Convert.ToInt32(txtDiscount.Text);
            per= Convert.ToInt32(txtPercant.Text);
            if (per > 0)
            {

                txtDiscount.Text =((per / 100) * grandTotal).ToString();
            }
            else if (txDiscount > 0)
            {
                per = txDiscount / grandTotal * 100;

                //per =  Math.Round(per, 3);
                per = Math.Truncate(per * 1000) / 1000;

                txtPercant.Text = Convert.ToString(per);
            }
```

Comment: it did limit the decimals to 3 after point but i am still facing a prob , the porb is when i am entering 12 in Price it says 12.33%, and when i put 12.33% it converts back it to 11.997Price which is not the same ans it should be... it should be exactly 12 not 11.997

Comment: @psnLoverCSharp: could you please share the code whcih you are trying?

Comment: nop told you that i am calculating % discount and price discount on grand total, means if i add 12% then it calculate the price discount of grand total and if i enter the price amount then it calculates the %discount of grand total

Comment: in txtGrandTotal i have grandtotal on which i have to calculate the discount in txtPercent i have % amount and in txtDiscount i've discount price

Comment: @psnLoverCSharp: you have added logic for only one way conversion...please check my edited post

Comment: no i didn't added one way conversion but have shown one in my code let me edit my question and post complete code of mine, may b then you can come to know where is actually prob arising

Answer (score 4):

First thing you must use `Decimal` and not `float` or `double`. To learn more read about *floating point precision*.

To round a given number use

```
 decimal percentage = 1.23456;
 decimal roundedValue= Math.Round(percentage, 3);
```

Of course you lose some precision after rounding; If, by design, there are no percentages with more than 3 precision digits it's the correct way to do it. But what if there is no limit? Then It means that

```
decimal square = roundedValue * roundValue;
```

gives you a different value from

```
decimal square = percentage * percentage;
```

So, one starts to think that perhaps rounding should only be done at the very end.

```
decimal square = Math.Round(percentage * percentage, 3);
```

It's better... but what if square is the input for another multiplication or division? Then the same loss of precision problem occurs.

Therefore what the application should be doing is to store the maximum precision possible but just output something nicer to the human behind the display.
This is accomplished by rounding only in the UI layer and not in the application layer

`Console.WriteLine("{0:F3}", d);`

Which you could abstract by providing a calculated property for your textbox

```
public string PercentageDisplay
{
  get { return decimalValue.ToString("{0:F3}"); }
}
///
txtPercant.Text = PercentageDisplay;
```