# C# Math.Round Up

Tags: c#, rounding

I've got a question.

I have a decimal and I want to round this at 2 decimals, not at the ordinary way but

0.2013559322033898305084745763

desired result: 0.21

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you round a number to two decimal places in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257005/how-do-you-round-a-number-to-two-decimal-places-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want a version of `Math.Ceiling`, but which takes a number of decimal places. You could just multiply, use `Math.Ceiling`, then divide again:

```
public static double CeilingWithPlaces(double input, int places)
{
    double scale = Math.Pow(10, places);
    double multiplied = input * scale;
    double ceiling = Math.Ceiling(multiplied);
    return ceiling / scale;
}
```

(If you *only* ever need 2 decimal places of course, you can hard-code the scale of 100, as Dennis_E's answer does.)

Now, two caveats about this:

- There may very well be situations where the fact that we're performing multiple operations works against you. Floating point maths can be weird like that, particularly with floating *binary* point. (Heck, the idea of "decimal places" with floating binary point is already problematic.)
- That will always round up, i.e. away from negative infinity. So it would round -0.201 to -0.20. If you want to round away from 0, you may need to handle negative values separately, e.g. with

  ```
  if (input < 0)
  {
      return -CeilingWithPlaces(-input, places);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Not directly, so you have to use a trick:

```
Math.Ceiling(x * 100) / 100;
```