# How to round up properly 4 and more decimal places into 2 in C#

Tags: c#, math, rounding

I need

```
Math.Round(42.5447, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

to result in `42.55`, but not in `42.54` as it does.

How to achieve this?

Comment: There is no such thing as proper rounding. It is culture dependent. Use CultureInfo that fits your requirement for rounding.

Comment: There certainly is proper rounding. But there are different rounding methods - and these are well-defined but not culture dependent.

Comment: Wow. It appeared (for me), that this kind of rounding is for bank systems. And mathematical method will give me the same as round method gives me - 42.54. My miss.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using doubles at all? If you are doing manipulations on decimal quantities then you should be using decimal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Math.Round Up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158334/c-sharp-math-round-up)

Answer (score 0):

Try `Ceiling` instead, with some multiply/divide trick:

```
Math.Ceiling((42.5447 * 100))/ 100
```