# Convert to decimal & format number to 2 digits after decimal mark

Tags: c#, visual-studio

The output from the code below produces a decimal number with 13 digits after decimal mark. I want to round off that number to only 2 digits after decimal mark. I've tried to use the `Decimal.Round Method` to no avail, apparently I'm not using it right.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TorrentPirate
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000);

            double downloadTime = time.TotalHours;

            double money = 50;

            double wifeSpending = money * downloadTime;



            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDecimal(wifeSpending));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about: `var value = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(wifeSpending), 2);`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257005/how-do-you-round-a-number-to-two-decimal-places-in-c

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with the method, just don't know how to implement it in this case...

Comment: Can you show the code where you try that method?

Comment: Math.Round(wifeSpending, 2);

            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDecimal(wifeSpending));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from your comments, you are doing it like this:

```
Math.Round(wifeSpending, 2);
```

The `Round` method does not change the variable that you pass in. It even couldn't if it wanted to because the `double` value is passed by value (not by reference).

What the `Round` method does is that it returns a new `double` that is rounded. Here is what you need to do:

```
wifeSpending = Math.Round(wifeSpending, 2);
```