# c# decimal keep only 2 decimals

Tags: c#, decimal

I have a decimal number: 12.4465463455

```
decimal value = 12.4465463455m;
```

How can I round this decimal and remove extra decimals but 2 so the decimal will be `12.45` ? Please notice I don't need a string. I know how to convert this to a string with 2 decimals and rounded. But have no idea how to manipulate the decimal variable itself.

Comment: `decimal result = Math.Round(value, 2);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you round a number to two decimal places in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257005/how-do-you-round-a-number-to-two-decimal-places-in-c)

Comment: Why does this question have that much downvotes? Only because it's a basic he could've looked up on google?

Comment: It's also an exact duplicate of another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `Math.Round`, so:

```
decimal value = 12.4465463455m;
decimal value2dp = Math.Round(value, 2); //2 => 2 decimal places
```