# How to round a decimal number?

Tags: c#

I have a decimal number  `decimal n = 0.111111111m;` and I want to change it to `0.112`. How could I do this ?

Comment: This answer shows how to round to 2 decimal places, change the number from 2 to 3:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257005/how-do-you-round-a-number-to-two-decimal-places-in-c

Comment: What results do you expect for these sample inputs - `0.1111` `0.1115` `0.1125` `-0.1111` `-0.1115` `-0.1125`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
Math.Round(n, 3);
```

To always round up, you can use:

```
Math.Ceiling(n * 1000) / 1000;
```

Comment: it works very well. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

According to this link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6be1edhb(v=vs.110).aspx

You'll need to do something like Decimal.Round(n, 3);

However your initial approximation is not accurate