# C#. Formatting my variables to show 2 digits after the decimal point. Can it be done in the Console.WriteLine() method

Tags: c#, function

```cs
using System;

namespace Toy_Shop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //pricing of the toys in the toy shop
            const double puzzlePrice = 2.60;
            const double dollPrice = 3.00;
            const double teddyBearPrice = 4.10;
            const double minionPrice = 8.20;
            const double toyTruckPrice = 2.00;

            //vacationPrice is the amount Petya needs to go on a vacation
            //the rest is the amount of each toy thta has been ordered
            double vacationPrice = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int puzzlesSold = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int dollsSold = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int teddyBearsSold = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int minionsSold = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int toyTrucksSold = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            int totalToys = puzzlesSold + dollsSold + teddyBearsSold + minionsSold + toyTrucksSold;
            double total = puzzlesSold * puzzlePrice + dollsSold * dollPrice + teddyBearsSold * teddyBearPrice + minionsSold * minionPrice + toyTrucksSold * toyTruckPrice;

            if(totalToys >= 50)
            {
                double totalWithDiscount = total - (total * 0.25);
                double finalIncome = totalWithDiscount - (totalWithDiscount * 0.1);
                bool vacation = finalIncome > vacationPrice;
                double moneyNeeded = (finalIncome - vacationPrice) * -1;
                
                if(vacation)
                    Console.WriteLine($"Yes! {finalIncome - vacationPrice} lv left.");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine($"Not enough money! {moneyNeeded} lv needed");
            }

            else
            {
                double finalIncome = total - (total * 0.1);
                bool vacation = finalIncome > vacationPrice;
                double moneyNeeded = (finalIncome - vacationPrice) * -1;

                if (vacation)
                    Console.WriteLine($"Yes! {finalIncome - vacationPrice} lv left.");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine($"Not enough money! {moneyNeeded} lv needed");

            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you round a number to two decimal places in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257005/how-do-you-round-a-number-to-two-decimal-places-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  float value = 145.352f;
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Number are: {0:N2} ", value));
  Console.ReadKey();
}
// Output: Number are: 145,35
```

More info [Standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: @Temix: please note that thanks is expressed by upvoting and/or marking as answer

Comment: Or preferably with string interpolation like used in the question: `Console.WriteLine($"Number are: {value:N2}");`

Comment: You don't need `string.Format` here. `Console.Writeline` expects the same type of parameters (a format string with placeholders and the objects to format). So `Console.WriteLine("Number is {0:N2}", value);` will produce equivalent results with one less function call (the added `string.Format`) That aside, interpolation as suggested by the other comment would work as well.

Comment: Of course it's not necessary string.Format. It's just one more option.

Answer (score 0):

// val = 1234.5678

```
    Console.WriteLine(val.ToString("N2"));//1234.56
```

// Or

```
     Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(val, 2));//1234.56
```